# Homology group of convex sets - boundedness condition

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homology-cohomology

In Rotman's Introduction to Algebraic Topology, pg 73, he shows that

> If $X$ is a **bounded** convex subspace of a eucliden space, then $H_n(X)=0$ for all $n \ge 1$.

His proof goes as follows:

> Define the cone construction homomoprhism $c_n:S_n(X) \rightarrow S_{n-1}(X)$ which satisfies 
>   $$ \partial_{n-1}c_n(\sigma) = \sigma - c_{n-1}\partial_n(\sigma).$$ 
>   for $\sigma \in S_n(X)$. This shows that $Z_n(X)=B_n(X)$.
>
> The cone is linear extension of the following: For a fix $b\in X$, on an $n$-simplex, $\sigma:\Delta^n \rightarrow X$, we define $b \cdot \sigma : \Delta^{n+1} \rightarrow X$ where 
>   $$ b \cdot \sigma:= 
> \begin{cases}
> b&  \text{ if } t_0=1 \\ 
> t_0b+(1-t_0)b(\frac{t_1}{1-t_0}, \ldots, \frac{t_{n+1}}{1-t_0} ) & \text{ if } t_0 \not= 1 
> \end{cases}
> $$

all that is required for the operation to be well defiend is that of convexity. Where is **boundedness** required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A convex subset of a Euclidean space is a star domain (with respect to any of its points), therefore it is contractible, from which it follows that its homology groups are all trivial.

The boundedness condition is either a typo or an artifact related to the definitions encountered thus far in the book.