# Small confusion regarding singular homology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

This is the proof of Theorem 4.19. in Joseph J. Rotman „An Introduction to Algebraic Topology“. We want to show that $H_n(X)=0$ for all $n>0$ and $X$ convex bounded in some euclidean space. I refer to a similar question [Homology group of convex sets - boundedness condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2861258/homology-group-of-convex-sets-boundedness-condition) for used notation, in short, $\gamma=\partial c\gamma+ c\partial\gamma$ for a chain $\gamma\in S_n(X)$. He then says that if $\gamma$ is a cycle, we have $\gamma =\partial c\gamma$, a boundary, so homology is trivial. But this I don‘t understand: is the cone over $0$ again $0$? In my eyes, I would see that the cone over $0$ is a boundary, which of course wouldn’t change the conclusion, but the argument confuses me a little.

Thanks in advance for any sort of clarification!

Answer (score 2):

I came to realise my mistake... the $0$-chain is not the zero simplex (which doesn't make any sense anyway, right?) but the neutral element in the group $S_n(X)$. I first deleted the question, but now I think one needs to stand by such wrong thoughts.

Comment: Rather than standing by "wrong thoughts", think of it as providing help for the next person who has the same question.